# Pull To Refresh a table view in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, rss, tableview, pull-to-refresh

I am totally new to SWIFT and to developing in general. I am currently building an RSS news feed to hone my (very limited) skills. I am basically parsing an RSS feed from a random news channel and then storing the titles in a simple table view.

I am trying to implement UIPullToRefresh using SWIFT, and truth be told I am kinda stuck! I have written the following code. As you can see I have added the necessary code to my viewDidLoad method. At this point the refresh spinner works well but I am now wondering what code is needed in my "refresh function" to actually refresh my table view.

I know this may seem trivial to most of you guys, but i am fairly new to this and i have been pulling my hair for the last 12 hours ... so anything would probably help at this point.

Thanks for your help!

```
    import UIKit

class BRTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate  {

    var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()
    var blogPosts: [BlogPost] = []
    var postTitle: String = String()
    var postLink: String = String()
    var postDate: String = String()

    var eName: String = String()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://rt.com/rss/")!
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        // pull to refresh the table view

        refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
    }


    func refresh(sender:AnyObject){
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://rt.com/rss/")!
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }


        // MARK: - NSXMLParserDelegate methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        eName = elementName
        if elementName == "item" {
            postTitle = String()
            postLink = String()
            postDate = String()
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
        let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if eName == "title" {
                postTitle += data
            } else if eName == "link" {
                postLink += data
            } else if eName == "pubDate" {
                postDate += data
            }
        }
    }

     func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            let blogPost: BlogPost = BlogPost()
            blogPost.postTitle = postTitle
            blogPost.postLink = postLink
            blogPost.postDate = postDate
            blogPosts.append(blogPost)
        }
    }

    override func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            self.tableView.reloadData();
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing();
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return blogPosts.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = blogPost.postTitle
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = blogPost.postDate.substringToIndex(advance(blogPost.postDate.startIndex, 25))


        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
         return 50.0
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)  {
        if segue.identifier == "viewpost" {
            let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
            let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[selectedRow!]
            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as PostViewController
            viewController.postLink = blogPost.postLink
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this fix the issue:

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject){
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()

}
```

This will re-parse the XML and update the `blogPosts` variable.

Remove the following line in `viewDidLoad`:

```
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

You should also override the `parserDidEndDocument` function to include this:

```
func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser!){

    self.tableView.reloadData();
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing();
}
```

This will refresh the table view once the parser is done.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your swift response! As mentioned i am very new to programing and i am still struggling with some of the basic stuff ... so here are my questions: 1) what exactly do you mean by "Store your UIRefreshControl as a class"  2) is this how you would override the parserDidEndDocument ?         override func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            self.refresh()
        }
    }
thanks so much for you help. I really appreciate!

Comment: 1. I've edited the question to address this and 2. That is correct, but you should update it what I have edited into the question.

Comment: I have added your updates but I had to omit "var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl" as i was getting an error and apparently UIRefreshControl is already UITableViewController already declares the refreshControl so i did not need to redeclare it ... that said i am still getting errors with the "override parserDidEndDocument" function ...

Comment: FYI - the errors I am getting are as follow:  1) method does not override any method from its super class    2)Invalid redeclaration of 'parser(_:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:)'    3) 'UIRefreshControl?' does not have a member named 'endRefreshing'   i am really sorry for all the hassle ... this thing is really driving me nuts ... thanks so much !

Comment: @user3694305 I've updated the question, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Your errors are because: 1) you don't need the word "override" in the definition of the parser:didEndElement: function; 2) in the same line of code, you have implemented `parser:didEndElement:` (a second time) - it should be `parserDidEndDocument()` as per @68cherries answer; and 3) self.refreshControl is optional, you need to unwrap by adding '?' as per @68cherries revised answer.